# Use vertcat to concatenate columns of a matrix using array of indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

Let's say we have the following random matrix

```
a=rand(6,5)

a =

    0.8147    0.2785    0.9572    0.7922    0.6787
    0.9058    0.5469    0.4854    0.9595    0.7577
    0.1270    0.9575    0.8003    0.6557    0.7431
    0.9134    0.9649    0.1419    0.0357    0.3922
    0.6324    0.1576    0.4218    0.8491    0.6555
    0.0975    0.9706    0.9157    0.9340    0.1712
```

and we have done an SVD decomposition of this matrix.

```
[U E V]=svd(a);
```

If we want to concatenate the first, third and fifth columns, we can do that like this

```
z=vertcat(U(:,1),U(:,3),U(:,5));
```

The dimensions of z are

```
[m,n]=size(z)

m =

    18


n =

     1
```

But suppose that I want the following thing: I will declare an array with elements of these indices or

```
b=[1 3 5]

b =

     1     3     5
```

and then

```
 z1=vertcat(U(:,b));
```

but the dimensions are

```
 [m1 n1]=size(z1)

m1 =

     6


n1 =

     3
```

Is it possible that in `z1=vertcat(U(:,b));` I change something so that it directly gives me result I want?

Comment: Please have a look at the edits I made to your post. Please keep those in mind the next time you ask a question. Properly capitalize your sentences and write "I" instead of "i".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at:

```
 a(:,1) =  0.8147    
           0.9058    
           0.1270    
           0.9134   
           0.6324    
           0.0975
```

You get a vertical vector. By doing `vertcat` you add the other vertical vectors vertically resulting in a `18x1`vector.
You could use `horzcat` if you want the other columns added as columns. By using `b` which is a horizontal vector MATLAB is changing the output accordingly. 
Because `svd` returns a matrix of the same dimension as the input, same goes for `U`.

 
**EDIT**

For getting a 18x1 vector as result use either:

```
z1=reshape(z1,18,1);
```

or use

```
z1=z1(:);
```

Comment: yes and that why i have asked,how can i do in this case?

Comment: idea is that we can choose automatically which columns i want,so please

Comment: ? I don't understand your question then. you want the result (`6x3`) and you are asking how to get it? Or what is it you want and where is the problem?

Comment: no i want to get result as 18X1,using array help,but it gives dimension 6X3

Comment: ah and you want to get that by using b?

Comment: ok so directly there is no way to do it  yes?in directly i meant from this code z1=vertcat(U(:,b));

Comment: I wouldn't know a direct way (except using a loop). I tried and compared `for-loop` with using `reshape` and `z1=z1(:)`. When using  `a=rand(50000,700); b=1:2:500;` the for-loop took 12 seconds, reshape: 0.08 and the last method 0.12. So `reshape` seems to be best, but the difference is marginal. Just don't use loops for this :D

Comment: Just be sure to use `z1=reshape(z1,numel(b)*u1(1),1);` where `u1=size(u);`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
z1 = U(:,b);
z1 = z1(:);
```

Comment: that i know,but directly is it not possible?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Please look at the edited answer, and tell me if you want a more direct approach

Comment: yes from here  z1=vertcat(U(:,b));  direct approaches

Answer (score 1):

what you done is proper, but you have to use reshape function at the last step, like that:

```
z1 = reshape(Z1,1,18);
```